# Change Chapter Placement Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I would like to set the chapter after title (or if titleaddon, after titleaddon, or if subtitle after subtitle, or if subtitle addon, after subtitle addon) instead of the end of the entry.

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  headings=standardclasses,
  listof=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.50cm, bottom=2.00cm, footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
% no period after addon titles
\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{lawtitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@inbook{iKonjaku.2003,
    author = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
    crossref = {Konjaku.2003},
    chapter = {11.1},
    publisher = {Shogakukan Inc},
    title = {Sh\={o}toku-taishi kono ch\={o} ni shite hajimete bupp\={o} o hirome tamau-go},
    titleaddon = {Die Geschichte von Prinz Sh\={o}toku, dem Ersten, der das Buddha-Dharma an diesem Morgen verbreitete},
    year = {2003}}
    

@book{Konjaku.2003,
    address = {T{\=o}ky{\=o}},
    author = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
    keywords = {primary},
    number = {1},
    organization = {Japan Knowledge},
    publisher = {Shogakukan Inc},
    series = {Shinpen Nihon koten bungaku zensh\={u} [Neuausgabe Gesamtwerke klassicher japanischer Literatur]},
    title = {Konjaku-monogatari-sh\={u}},
    titleaddon = {Geschichtensammlung von Jetzt und Einst},
    volume = {35},
    year = {2003}}

\end{filecontents}
% Step 3: Add defined file as resource
\begin{document}
 \nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chapter is printed by the bibmacro `chapter+pages`, so you just need to move this bibmacro in the definition of the relevant bibliography drivers (`@inbook`, `@incollection` and `@inproceedings` for consistency). The definitions of those drivers can be found in [`ext-standard.bbx`](https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/tree/release/ext-standard.bbx).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{lawtitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{crosscite}{inbook:parent}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:related} and not test {\iffieldxref{related}}}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{crosscite}{incollection:parent}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:related} and not test {\iffieldxref{related}}}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{introcite:plain}%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{crosscite}{inproceedings:parent}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{togl {bbx:related} and not test {\iffieldxref{related}}}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{iKonjaku.2003,
  author     = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
  crossref   = {Konjaku.2003},
  chapter    = {11.1},
  publisher  = {Shogakukan Inc},
  title      = {Sh\={o}toku-taishi kono ch\={o} ni shite hajimete bupp\={o} o hirome tamau-go},
  titleaddon = {Die Geschichte von Prinz Sh\={o}toku, dem Ersten,
                der das Buddha-Dharma an diesem Morgen verbreitete},
  year       = {2003},
}
@book{Konjaku.2003,
  address      = {T{\=o}ky{\=o}},
  author       = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
  keywords     = {primary},
  number       = {1},
  organization = {Japan Knowledge},
  publisher    = {Shogakukan Inc},
  series       = {Shinpen Nihon koten bungaku zensh\={u}
                  [Neuausgabe Gesamtwerke klassicher japanischer Literatur]},
  title        = {Konjaku-monogatari-sh\={u}},
  titleaddon   = {Geschichtensammlung von Jetzt und Einst},
  volume       = {35},
  year         = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you don't like to copy that much code just to move around a few lines, you can use [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to patch the drivers

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyvt,
  datamodel=customstyles,
  maxnames=25,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  usetranslator=true,
  alldates=terse,
  labeldate=year,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  url=false
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\titleaddonpunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\DeclareFieldAlias{booktitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{maintitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{journaltitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{lawtitleaddon}{titleaddon}
\DeclareFieldAlias{subtitleaddon}{titleaddon}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*{\MoveChapAndPagesInDriver}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {}
    {}
    {\PackageError
       {patch-biblatex}
       {Failed to remove 'chapter+pages' from @#1 driver}
       {}}%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{in:}}
    {\newunit\newblock
     \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \usebibmacro{in:}}
    {}
    {\PackageError
       {patch-biblatex}
       {Failed to remove 'chapter+pages' from @#1 driver}
       {}}%
}

\MoveChapAndPagesInDriver{inbook}
\MoveChapAndPagesInDriver{incollection}
\MoveChapAndPagesInDriver{inproceedings}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{iKonjaku.2003,
  author     = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
  crossref   = {Konjaku.2003},
  chapter    = {11.1},
  publisher  = {Shogakukan Inc},
  title      = {Sh\={o}toku-taishi kono ch\={o} ni shite hajimete bupp\={o} o hirome tamau-go},
  titleaddon = {Die Geschichte von Prinz Sh\={o}toku, dem Ersten,
                der das Buddha-Dharma an diesem Morgen verbreitete},
  year       = {2003},
}
@book{Konjaku.2003,
  address      = {T{\=o}ky{\=o}},
  author       = {Mabuchi, Kazuo and Kunisaku, Fumimaro and Inagaki Taichi},
  keywords     = {primary},
  number       = {1},
  organization = {Japan Knowledge},
  publisher    = {Shogakukan Inc},
  series       = {Shinpen Nihon koten bungaku zensh\={u}
                  [Neuausgabe Gesamtwerke klassicher japanischer Literatur]},
  title        = {Konjaku-monogatari-sh\={u}},
  titleaddon   = {Geschichtensammlung von Jetzt und Einst},
  volume       = {35},
  year         = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \nocite{*} 
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result

[image: Mabuchi, Kazuo, Fumimaro Kunisaku und Inagaki Taichi (2003b). „Shotoku-taishi konocho ni shite hajimete buppo o hirome tamau-go“ [Die Geschichte von Prinz Shotoku, dem Ersten, der das Buddha-Dharma an diesem Morgen verbreitete]. Kap. 11.1. In: Konjaku-monogatari-shi [Geschichtensammlung von Jetzt und Einst]. Bd. 35. Shinpen Nihon koten bungaku zenshi [Neuausgabe Gesamtwerke klassicher japanischer Literatur] 1. Tokyo: Shogakukan Inc.]

is the same in both cases.

Comment: Thank you! it worked